# Set environment variable

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I need some environment variables for my project. I placed it in the `launchSettings.json` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1). I know it is VS-specific feature but it works fine with `dotnet run` cli command and it looks good for me. However it doesn't work for `dotnet publish` command. How should I set environment variables for production? I'd like to place it inside the project without using powershell, docker etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *entire* purpose of using environment variables is so that they *are not part of your project*. If you *want* them to be in your project, then just use appsettings.json. That's what it's for.

Comment: You changed your question after I wrote my answer.

Comment: I need environment variables exactly because it uses some library that is included to the project via nuget. I cannot change it :(

Comment: The library requires environment variables to be set? If that's the case, and it's outside of your control, then you will have to write a powershell script or equivalent to get the job done. There's no built-in functionality for this because again, it's not the way it's supposed to be handled.

Comment: At least I can set it in the web.config. However it is deprecated way and I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Well, yes and no. The web.config is an artifact that exists solely for hosting in IIS. It's not utilized by ASP.NET Core, and thus, is not reliable. It can be overwritten, discarded, etc.